# Puppet get / partition filesystem type using facter

Tags: filesystems, puppet, facter

I want to determine which filesystem type the `/` partition has.

`facter mountpoints` shows:

```
/home => {
  available => "1.81 GiB",
  available_bytes => 1946107904,
  capacity => "2.01%",
  device => "/dev/sda/home",
  filesystem => "xfs",
  options => [
    "rw",
    "relatime",
    "attr2",
    "inode64",
    "noquota"
  ],
  size => "1.85 GiB",
  size_bytes => 1986002944,
  used => "38.05 MiB",
  used_bytes => 39895040
},
```

I want only the filesystem type (like xfs,ext2, etc.)

What should the hash access look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access values in a hash, use `$hash_name['key name']`, so use `$facts`, access the `mountpoints` key, then the `/` key, then the `filesystem` key in order:

```
$root_filesystem = $facts['mountpoints']['/']['filesystem']
```

More information: [Puppet language: Hashes: Accessing values](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_data_hash.html#accessing-values).